# React hooks - Remove multi object from array and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to delete multiple objects of array  and update the state?
I have selected multiple items from checkbox 
This is the selected item [5, 4, 3]
I want to remove all items in array based on id and update the state
This is my code

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState();

 const DeleteProducts = () => {
  const selectedItems = [5, 4, 3];

    selectedItems.forEach(function(p) {
      setProducts(products.filter(prd => prd.id !== p));
    });
}
```

Its removing only one item at time, but I selected 3 items. How to show remaining items except 3 selected items in products state?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it to a single filter function:

```
const DeleteProducts = () => {
  setProducts(prevProducts => {
    return prevProducts.filter(p => ! p.selected);
  });
}
```