# React hooks - Remove multi items from array and update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to delete multiple items of array and set state? I have selected multiple items from checkbox. This is the selected item [5, 4, 3] I want to remove all items in array based on id and update the state. This is my code.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState();

 const DeleteProducts = () => {
  const selectedItems = [5, 4, 3];

    selectedItems.forEach(function(p) {
      setProducts(products.filter(prd => prd.id !== p));
    });
}
```

Its removing only one item at time, but I selected 3 items. How to remove 3 selected items and  products state?
Thanks

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question a few hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299645/react-hooks-remove-multi-object-from-array-and-update-state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks - Remove multi object from array and update state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299645/react-hooks-remove-multi-object-from-array-and-update-state)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling setProducts ever iteration of the loop. You have to call setProducts after you filter them so that it only triggers state change once

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState();

 const DeleteProducts = () => {
  const selectedItems = [5, 4, 3];
  let newProducts;
    selectedItems.forEach(function(p) {
      newProducts = products.filter(prd => prd.id !== p);
    });
  setProducts(newProducts);
}
```

better yet you can filter it faster like this without looping

```
const DeleteProducts = () => {
  const selectedItems = [5, 4, 3];
  const newProducts = products.filter(prd => selectedItems.indexOf(prd.id) >= 0);
  setProducts(newProducts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, also I think you forgot to instantiate an empty array in newProducts variable, because that will become undefined